CDO combined commands not working
I am working in R and have netCDF files that I need to pre-process beforehand.
One file can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14tbMvFaYSvHpDWTOdbSSdverkowEhNyV/view?usp=share_link
There are daily 0.25 ERA5 variables:
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 720, 1440, 1036800, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : t2m.daily.an.era5.1440.720.2018.nc 
names      : X2018.01.01, X2018.01.02, X2018.01.03, X2018.01.04, X2018.01.05, X2018.01.06, X2018.01.07, X2018.01.08, X2018.01.09, X2018.01.10, X2018.01.11, X2018.01.12, X2018.01.13, X2018.01.14, X2018.01.15, ... 
Date       : 2018-01-01, 2018-12-31 (min, max)
varname    : t2m 

I need to remap from 0.25 to 0.5 + select a specific area.
I have tried the following with CDO:
#!/bin/sh

var=$1
yr=$2
name=$3

flist=/****/****/**/0d25_daily/${var}/${var}.daily.an.era5.1440.720.${yr}*

for f in $flist; do
echo $f 

cdo  -remapbil,r720x360 -sellonlatbox,-80,10,-20,15 $f ${name}_daily_ERA5_${yr}.nc

done

however when I open the file in R, I get 0 layers while normally for one year I should get a layer per day.
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 0  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -180.25, 179.75, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : Tair_daily_ERA5_2018.nc 
names      : layer 
varname    : t2m 


Hard to help without either sample input file or a sample of your output. Can you link to one of the input source netCDFs?

I updated my post

When I run that cdo script (with the file name for $f, and out.nc for the output) on that one file linked I do get 365 layers when reading out.nc using raster::brick or terra::rast. I cant replicate your problem. Can you re-form your Q with this one file so you can take out the shell script and show your R code and versions, and the output from cdo?

I'm using:
CDO version 2.0.4, Copyright (C) 2003-2022 MPI für Meteorologie

and I run:
$ cdo  -remapbil,r720x360 -sellonlatbox,-80,10,-20,15 \
    t2m.daily.an.era5.720.360.2018.nc t2m_daily_ERA5_2018.nc

Which then outputs:
cdo(1) sellonlatbox: Process started
cdo    remapbil: Bilinear weights from lonlat (180x70) to lonlat (720x360) grid
cdo(1) sellonlatbox: Processed 94608000 values from 1 variable over 365 timesteps.
cdo    remapbil: Processed 4599000 values from 1 variable over 365 timesteps [42.11s 153MB].

gdalinfo on the output NetCDF looks okay, which is a semi-independent check on whether its the file or R that's the problem:
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: t2m_daily_ERA5_2018.nc
Size is 720, 360
Origin = (-0.250000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.500000000000000,-0.500000000000000)
[...]
Band 1 Block=720x91 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
  Unit Type: K
  Metadata:
    long_name=2 metre temperature
    missing_value=-9999
    NETCDF_DIM_time=158959
    NETCDF_VARNAME=t2m
    units=K
    _FillValue=-9999
Band 2 Block=720x91 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
  Unit Type: K
  Metadata:
    long_name=2 metre temperature
    missing_value=-9999
    NETCDF_DIM_time=158960
    NETCDF_VARNAME=t2m
    units=K
    _FillValue=-9999
[...]

up to band 365. So then I can read into R using raster:
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> b = brick("./t2m_daily_ERA5_2018.nc")
Loading required namespace: ncdf4
> b
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 360, 720, 259200, 365  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -0.25, 359.75, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : t2m_daily_ERA5_2018.nc 
names      : X2018.01.01, X2018.01.02, X2018.01.03, X2018.01.04, X2018.01.05, X2018.01.06, X2018.01.07, X2018.01.08, X2018.01.09, X2018.01.10, X2018.01.11, X2018.01.12, X2018.01.13, X2018.01.14, X2018.01.15, ... 
Date       : 2018-01-01, 2018-12-31 (min, max)
varname    : t2m 

and it has all 365 layers. This is using:
> packageVersion("raster")
[1] ‘3.6.26’

but it also works with the terra package:
> library(terra)
> b = rast("./t2m_daily_ERA5_2018.nc")
> plot(b[[100]])

Not sure if this is your expected result though:

This is with R 4.3.1 on Linux.

Thank you very much! It's bizarre, i will check my CDO version and terra ones as well. If i want to change the extent to -180 to 180, how can I ? I thought sellonlatbox would do it automatically.

Don't know how to do it in cdo (never used it before) but the rotate function in the terra package does exactly this.
